# Proving a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Show that $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ defined by $T(u)=Mu$ (multiplication by $M$, an $m \times n$ matrix) is a linear combination.

I know I need to prove that the function preserves vector addition and scalar multiplication by showing that:

1) $T(v_1 + v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2)$

2) $T(\lambda v) = \lambda T(v)$

but I don't know how to start doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just start writing what LHS is and go towards what RHS is :P

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Best way to prove an equality.

Comment: You will need to use that matrix multiplication satisfies pretty much the same properties. $M(v_1+v_2)=Mv_1+Mv_2$, and $M(\lambda v)=\lambda Mv$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself: a lot simpler than I was thinking.

$T(u_1 + u_2) = M(u_1+u_2) = Mu_1 + Mu_2 = T(u_1) + T(u_2)$

Therefore, vector addition is preserved.

$T(\lambda u) = M(\lambda u) = \lambda (Mu) = \lambda T(u)$

Therefore, scalar multiplication is preserved and T is a linear transformation.